# ADFS COnfiguration Issue - an error occurred during an attempt to set the spn for the specified service account

Tags: java, spring, saml, adfs

I have installed ADFS in my windows server 2012. After successful configuration i got warning like "an error occurred during an attempt to set the spn for the specified service account" any one let us know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

ServicePrincipalName it is trying to register, already exists. Change your server host name. It's mentioned in this blog : http://msexchangeguru.com/2016/10/02/adfs-spn-conflict/